# Informative feedback from assert with matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, assert

Does there exist a simple function in Matlab that will give more informative feedback when using assert with matrices than the simple application of the `assert` function?

My simple application is:

```matlab
>> assert(all([1 2; 3 4] == [1 2; 3 5], 'all'))
Assertion failed.
```

In Python, with `numpy.testing.assert_equal` the feedback from a failed assertion shows the two arrays.

I guess it would be possible to define further the arguments to the `assert` function `errmsg`, `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: Have you not answered your own question with the last sentence? You could also consider using `validateattributes`, but that's not usually for performing comparisons. Or check the condition outside of an assertion to have completely free choice what happens if it is false. It would help if you included what you want your actual output/behaviour to be, "more informative" is pretty subjective

Comment: I am not familiar with `validateattributes` and cannot see you to call that function to give an informative feedback. An informative feedback could show the two matrices or indices and elements that are wrong. This is was `numpy.testing` does.

Comment: If you want to compare elements of matrices with the same dimensions, just print the result of matrixA==matrixB. The result will be a matrix of logical values.

Comment: @picchiolu How would you use that together with the assert?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You want to use assert, but you also want outputs which assert doesn't give you. Pick what matters o you, if it's the format of the output then make your own and throw an `error` if your logical test fails instead of letting `assert` do that for you.

Comment: @FinnÅrupNielsen I posted an example as an answer. There are several ways of using ```assert```: the one I provided takes advantage of the fact that ```assert``` can throw a custom error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assert` is to validate intermediate values inside your code, so you get an error when something is not as you expect, and you can debug it. This is the “fail early” philosophy. You don’t need to get a detailed output here, it tells you that you need to break out the debugger.

Your use case seems closer to testing the output of a function, to verify it works as intended. This is a very different use case, for which MATLAB has [the testing framework](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-based-unit-tests.html).

For example, your equality comparison would be implemented through [`verifyEqual`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.qualifications.verifiable.verifyequal.html):

```matlab
testCase = matlab.unittest.TestCase.forInteractiveUse;
verifyEqual(testCase,A,B)
```

Comment: Indeed, using the testing framework provides tons of details about the comparison. In my answer I adopted a more "customized" approach, which might provide more control on the quantity and kind of output produced and on the flow of the program in case an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the many ways `assert` can be used in conjunction with the `try/catch` and `throw` commands to catch errors and take specific actions (e.g. print a message and throw an exception that can be captured by the calling function:

```
function out = myfun(A, B)

out = 0;

try
   assert(all(size(A)==size(B)), 'Matrix sizes do not match')
catch exc % contains the message passed by assert
   fprintf('Size of A is: %d, %d\n',size(A)); % show the actual dimensions
   fprintf('Size of B is: %d, %d\n',size(B));
   out = 1;
   throw(exc) % throws exc and returns control to the caller
end

try
    assert(isequal(A,B), 'Matrix are not identical.')
catch exc % contains the message passed by assert
    disp(A==B) % show 0 where elements don't match
    out = 1;
    throw(exc) % throws exc and returns control to the caller
end

end
```

Calling `myfun` with `A=ones(4,4)` and `B=ones(4,5)` produces the following output:

[image]

Calling `myfun` with `A=ones(4,4)` and `B=2*ones(4,4)` leads to:

[image]

As I mentioned at the very beginning, the function above represent one of the possible implementations.